# Using PHP active record ORMs without database connection

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, orm, propel

Is it possible to use such ORMs as Propel or Yii's ActiveRecord without database connection?

There's a Yii2 project in which I need PHP not to communicate to database directly but via the UNIX socket. Best case scenario is extending/rewriting Yii's `Model::class` and being able to execute any CRUD method in a way that it'd generate a plain SQL and send it in the socket. I've looked through Yii's `Model::class`, `Query::class` and `QueryBuilder::class` source codes and it looks like they always need an instance of database connection.

Right now, for me, it seems like it's not even possible.

A worse (but still good, though) scenario is using Propel. I know it has a `toString()` method when building queries, but, as far as I know, it's not possible to use it in methods of models generated by Propel (like `$user->getPhotos()`, etc.).

Now I'm wondering whether it's even possible and, perhaps, there different kind of tools for this?

Comment: Yii wraps [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) [see](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.17/framework/db/CDbConnection.php#L445) you may investigate replace that

Comment: It sounds like you want to do more than just use propel without a database, which is possible, but you want to replace it with... something else? Or do you just want the ability to get between your active record implementation and the database? Also, am understanding of your use case seems like a necessity in order to provide an answer that meets your needs.